# When is the use of internal signals required in VDHL processes?

Tags: circuit-design, vhdl

Cheers. I am trying to create a toggle D flip flop in VHDL.
My try was :

```
entity DFFwTOGGLE is
    port(
    D,CLK: in std_logic;
    Q: out std_logic;
    );
end DFFwTOGGLE;

architecture behav of DFFwTOGGLE is
begin
    process(CLK)
begin
    if (CLK = '1' and CLK'event) then
        Q <= not Q;
    end if;
end process;
end behav;
```

some code I found online however uses internal signals inside the architecture, and then sets the $$Q <= Q IN$$ after the process. Why am I mistaken? More generally, when should I use internal signals? Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

In VHDL, before VHDL-2008, you cannot read from an output signal (after all, it is an output which you can write to, not an input which you can read from). That means that if you cannot read from it in order to manipulate it. You can only manipulate it by completely overwriting it without knowing what it was. So if you do need to read from it to change it (i.e. adding or subtracting from it), you need to do it to an internal signal before placing it on an output.

Comment: You could also make Q mode `buffer` which would also work under earlier revisions of the VHDL standard.